# Unique number field in database table but not primary key

Tags: sql-server, database, entity-framework

I have a testing system. It generates blank with numbers.Numbers **must** be unique. Blanks data are stored in MSSQL table. That's why I decided that number of blank will be primary key.
E.g

I have blanks in table

```
Id User
-----------
1  Alpha
2  Bravo
3  Charlie
```

I print 3 blanks for 3 users: Aplpha got blank with number 1, Bravo got blank with number 2

But there is a buisness rule. Blank Numbers can change. And I decided make this change to table: I added column BlankNumber with unique index

```
Id User     BlankNumber
-----------
1  Alpha    1
2  Bravo    2
3  Charlie  3
```

Now I can easily change this number by chaning *BlankNumber* column value

My question is how can I quickly generate value for column *BlankNumber*?
There will be collisions if I will not use transactions. But I don't want transactions because it slow down inserting data.

1) Is there custom column value generator not primary key? Are they supported by ORM (EF)?

2) If I decide to use transactions which isolation level should I select?

Comment: Does the value of Blank Number matter, or correlate to the data in any way?

Comment: Can't you use a guid (globally unique identifier)? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @AlexanderDerck no. It must be unique number not guid.

Comment: @Zabari It will be convinient if blank number will be sequential numbers but I must can change this numbers easily

Comment: Change them in what way?

Comment: @Zabari manually. If I have blanks numbered 1,2,3 I must be able to replace numbers 1,3,2 If I have these blanks 1,3,5 I must be able to replace them as 1,2,3. I can achieve that by using not primary key but another field